# Rigify. Question about Axis

Tags: rigging, axis

I turn on my axis, but it does show on my every bone
only one shows at the root
Thanks. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It's showing you the axis of the armature object, because you enabled axis in properties/object.  Enable viewport display in properties/object *data*/viewport display to enable the display of axes for each bone contained within the armature.

Comment: Thanks.  so where is properties?

Comment: I found it  thanks!!!!!!